# query the data and render to display

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def report(request)
    '''''''
     reportperson = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report=report_id)[:2]
   '''''''
return render(request,'report.html',{ 'reportperson':reportperson,})
```

template

```
{{ reportperson }}
```

My problem is the queried output is suppose to be like this "John" but instead i am getting the output as  `[<ReportPerson: John>]` with models name as prefix.

I am suppose to display the values in db like this format john,paul,william.But i am getting the output lie this []

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `report.html` template, do this:

```
{% for i in reportperson %}
  {{ i }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

You are returning a list and if you just display it like `{{ reportperson }}`, you will get a string version of the list.

Comment: `filter()` gives you a QuerySet, his `[:2]` evaluates the QuerySet and makes it into a list.

Comment: {{ i }} might print the person object. If you want to print the name, use {{ i.name }}

Comment: `{{ i }}` will print whatever `__unicode__()` returns for that object, if that method is not defined; then it will return some text representation.